# Pass date values from dataframe to query in Spark /Scala

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, hive

I have a dataframe having a date column and has values as below.

```scala
df.show()
+----+----------+
|name|       dob|
+----+----------+
| Jon|2001-04-15|
| Ben|2002-03-01|
+----+----------+
```

Now i need to query a table in hive which has "dob" from above dataframe (both 2001-04-15, 2002-03-01).So I need to pass the values under dob column as a parameter to my hive query.

I tried to collect the values to a variable like below which give me array of string.

```scala
val dobRead = df.select("updt_d").distinct().as[String].collect()
dobRead: Array[String] = Array(2001-04-15, 2002-03-01)
```

However when i try to pass to the query i see its not substituting properly and get error.

```scala
val tableRead = hive.executeQuery(s"select emp_name,emp_no,martial_status from <<table_name>> where dateOfBirth in ($dobRead)")
```

```sh
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Failed to compile query: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException: line 1:480 cannot recognize input near '(' '[' 'Ljava' in expression specification
```

Can you please help me how to pass date values to a query in spark.

Comment: Have you tried printing the SQL expression without executing it? This could help to debug your issue...

Comment: I get the below when i print

scala> println(dobRead)
[Ljava.lang.String;@54eaf69d

And the same gets substituted in the query 

scala>println(s"select emp_name,emp_no,martial_status from <> where dateOfBirth in ($dobRead)")
select emp_name,emp_no,martial_status from <> where dateOfBirth in ([Ljava.lang.String;@54eaf69d)

Comment: `select emp_name,emp_no,martial_status from <> where dateOfBirth in ($dobRead) ` is not a valid query in itself

Comment: `val sqlQuery = s"select emp_name,emp_no,martial_status from <> where dateOfBirth in ($dobRead)" println(sqlQuery)`

Answer (score 0):

You can collect the dates as follows ([Row.getAs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row)):

```
val rows: Array[Row] = df.select("updt_d").distinct().collect()
val dates: Array[String] = rows.map(_.getAs[String](0))
```

And then build the query:

```
val hql: String = s"select ... where dateOfBirth in (${
  dates.map(d => s"'${d}'").mkString(", ")
})"
```

### Option 2

If the number of dates in first DataFrame is too big, you should use join operations instead of collecting them into the driver.

First, load every table as DataFrames (I'll call them `dfEmp` and `dfDates`). Then you can join on date fields to filter, either using a standard `inner` join plus filtering out null fields or using directly a `left_semi` join:

```
val dfEmp = hiveContext.table("EmpTable")
val dfEmpFiltered = dfEmp.join(dfDates,
  col("dateOfBirth") === col("updt_d"), "left_semi")
```

Comment: +1 to Option 2. And if you use `...join(broadcast(dfDates),...`, Spark will collect dates dataframe  to the driver and distribute it to executors "automagically", to perform a more efficient mapside join.

Comment: Thanks @Civyshk I tried option 1, however when i run it i get below error. val hqlQuery: String = s"select emp_name,emp_no,martial_status FROM <<table>> where dateOfBirth in (${dates.mkString(", ")})" hqlQuery: String = select emp_name,emp_no,martial_status FROM <<table>> where dateOfBirth in (2020-03-01, 2020-02-15) I run in the above query it's taking the values as Int and unable to substitute. And get error like org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Line 0:-1 Wrong arguments '15': The arguments for IN should be the same type! Types are: {date IN (int, int)}

Comment: How do it make is pass values with single quotes like this ('2001-04-15',' 2002-03-01').

Comment: @danielMosses You can map every element in dates: val dates: Array[String] = rows.map(_.getAs[String](0)).map(d => s"'${d}'")